# how to put key of element to disk when used bigmemory

Tags: ehcache-bigmemory

I want to config hybrid mode to store the data on offheap and if offheap is full the data can be stored on disk,and how to put the key of element to disk?if you know,can you tell me how to put the key of the element on disk when I used the hybrid mode?

Comment: the version of bigmemory is bigmemory-max-4.3